# has or have need to use if we talk about group of peoples?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Sometimes I get confused while watching movies and reading newspapers. Because, some people use the "be" form as **has/have** respectively. So I have a doubt about its usage. Can anyone please help me?

For example: Some of my friends **has/have** iphone 6 mobile phone.

Comment: This is a good question because *some* is used for both - singular and plural making such construction interesting!

Comment: "*some* of my friends" is plural, "*one* of my friends" is singular.

Comment: hi all thanks for your kind reply, special thanks to mamta for Edited my question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is subject-verb agreement. Remember the basic rules and you're good to go!

From [Purdue OWL: Subject/Verb Agreement](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/):

> When two or more singular nouns or pronouns are connected by or or
>   nor, use a singular verb. *The book or the pen is in the drawer.* 3.
>   When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or
>   pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of
>   the subject that is nearer the verb.

Further in detail, [20 Rules of Subject Verb Agreement](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/20-Rules-of-subject-verb-agreement.html)

So the correct answer for your question would be

> Some of my friends **have** iPhone 6 mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

You got confused because 'some' is used for both - singular and plural. But then in such construction as user3169 says, some reflects plural.

So,

> Some of my friends ***have*** iphone 6

If you want to make it singular, you may say...

> One of my friends ***has*** iphone 6

If you are **not** sure about who is that *one*, some is also used singularly for unknown person

> Some friend in my group **has** iphone 6

Comment: BTW, *an* iPhone 6.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! But IMO, it's a proper noun so no indefinite article here! I'll say exactly what [Apple says in its **manual**](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf)- *"If you have iphone 6...you can also use the Touch ID..."*

Comment: The problem is that *only* Apple writes it that way, and it's quite strange of them to do so.  Everyone else uses proper grammar when discussing iPhones.